# How do I get this to reduce/simplify further?

Tags: differential-geometry

These equations set up an operation I'm trying to do to calculate the Christoffel Symbol:

```
X[r_, theta_] := r*Cos[theta]; 
Y[r_, theta_] := r*Sin[theta]; 
R[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]; 
Theta[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];
```

So I now perform the calculation which is equivalent to:$$\Gamma^{r}_{\theta \theta}=\frac{\partial^2x}{\partial^2\theta}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial^2\theta}\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}$$
My implementation is:

```
Simplify[D[D[X[r, theta], theta], theta]*D[R[x, y], x] + D[D[Y[r, theta], theta], theta]*D[R[x, y], y] /. {y -> Y[r, theta], x -> X[r, theta]}]
```

Which works, but gives me the answer:$$-\sqrt{r^2}$$
It appears to my untrained eyes that this is equivalent to $-r$ (which is the real answer I'm after).  How do I force mathematica to reduce this?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Mathematica does not simplify `Sqrt[r^2]` to `r` due to the fact that `r` could be negative, or positive, and `r^2` will yield the same result, however the `Sqrt` function is defined to only result in in the positive value of `r`.

If you assume that r is always positive, then `-Sqrt[r^2]` can be simplified to `-r`

Comment: `Sqrt[r^2]` is just another way to write `Abs[r]` (absolute value)

Comment: $r$ is the radius and can't be negative (radius can't be negative, can it?).  Can I force this to reduce by setting assumption telling the simplification that $r$ can only be positive?  If so, would you please suggest how to do this (I'm still pretty new to Mathematica).

Comment: Yes, you can use `Assumptions->` .
Here is documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html
In your case, you can use the following code to simplify, which will output `-r` 
Code:
`Simplify[D[D[X[r, theta], theta], theta]*D[R[x, y], x] + D[D[Y[r, theta], theta], theta]*D[R[x, y], y] /. {y -> Y[r, theta], x -> X[r, theta]}, Assumptions->r>0]`